# How to read values from a 2D initializer_list and put them in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a Matrix class which has to have a constructor that accepts an uninitialized list.
The contstructor has to get the values and put them in a 2D vector, a matrix.

This is my 2D vector.

```
vector<vector<double>> d_matrix;
```

This is my constructor.

```
Matrix::Matrix(initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> list)
{
    d_row = list.size();
    d_col = (*list.begin()).size();

    initMatrix();

    for (size_t r = 0; r < d_row; ++r)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < d_col; ++c)
        {
            /* I need to do something here */
            //d_matrix[r][c] = list.begin() + r) + c);
            //cout << (*list.begin()).;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my init Matrix function to start off with initial values.

```
void Matrix::initMatrix()
{
    d_matrix.resize(d_col, vector<double>(d_row, 0)); 
}
```

This is how I call my constructor.

```
Matrix m({ {1, 2, 3},
           {3, 4, 2} }
         );
```

I managed to obtain the dimensions of the list(d_row and d_col), however I am stuck with trying to extract the values out of the list, tried it with an insert aswell and both the iterators begin and end. The uninitialized list class only seems to have two iterator methods and a size method. I am using namespace *std* btw.

The question is, how do I get the values out of the uninitialized list and store them into my 2D vector which I call d_matrix.

Comment: Not sure if this works but can you try: `list.begin()[r].begin()[c]`? According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), the iterator type is a pointer. The list doesn't support array subscript operators but begin and end. Your attempt `list.begin() + r` is still a pointer to a row (which is a list again) so you need to dereference it. So the `[]` should do it.

Comment: Also note that you don't check for equally sized rows. You should add an assert in your row-loop.

Comment: @leemes Why didn't I think of that...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, unless you need to convert between row-major and column-major (i.e. transpose the matrix) I guess you could simply write `d_matrix = list`... Not sure if it works though. Note that it also replaces the initMatrix call in this case.

Comment: Equals operator on vector<vector<>> vs unitialized_list<unitialized_list<>> doesn't work, crap load of template errors

Comment: Ah, maybe because you take a list of list of **ints**, but your matrix is a vector of vector of **doubles**. Are you sure you want to take ints in your ctor?

Comment: @leemes It will be a template class eventually, just getting the outline going. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all**: you should initialize members in the initialization list after the parameter list in the constructor definition, otherwise you are doing assignment. And you should also pass your `std::initializer_list` as *reference to const* to avoid unnecessary copying.

```
Matrix::Matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>& list)
    : d_row(list.size()), d_col((*list.begin()).size()) {
    // ...
}
```

**Secondly**: don't use `resize` on the vector to default construct the vector elements, instead use `reserve` like this:

```
d_matrix.reserve(d_row); // Allocate storage for vector elements.
```

There's really no need to allocate memory for the elements in the nested vectors as they are of built in type `double` (no ctors).

**Thirdly**: if you change the element type of the nested `std::initializer_list<int>` parameter in the constructor to `double`, like this:

```
Matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>>& list)
```

Then all you have to do to transfer the elements to your matrix in the constructor is:

```
for (const auto& l : list) {
    d_matrix.emplace_back(l);
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/jLq48Z)

If you want to keep the `int` type and do an explicit cast you could do something like this instead:

```
d_matrix.resize(d_row, std::vector<double>(d_col, 0));
decltype(d_row) r = 0;
for (const auto& l : list) {
    decltype(d_col) c = 0;
    for (const auto d : l) {
        d_matrix[r][c++] = d;
    }
    ++r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a constructor then you need not to call inside it member function initMatrix.

I think it will be enough to use the fllowing code snippet (without testing):

```
d_matrix.resize( list.size() );
std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type i = 0;
for ( const std::initializer_list<int> &l : list )
{
   d_matrix[i].reserve( l.size() );
   for ( int x : l ) d_matrix[i].push_back( x );
   ++i;
}
```

I am sorry. It seems it can be done simpler.

```
d_matrix.resize( list.size() );
std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type i = 0;
for ( const std::initializer_list<int> &l : list )
{
   d_matrix[i].assign( l );
   ++i;
}
```

Maybe you can even write one line of code

```
d_matrix.assign( list );
```